# What's the syntax to derive a generic class from another generic class when both have constraints?

Tags: c#, class, generics, derived

I have a base generic class defined as follows:

```
public class TheBaseClass<T> where T : Interface1 {}
```

I have another generic class that I'd like to derive from TheBaseClass. It's defined as follows:

```
public class SomeClass<T> where T : Interface2 {}
```

I've looked through the docs, but I can't find an example that compiles. All suggestions will be gratefully received.

Comment: You can´t change a constraint of the base-class. Is there any relation between the two interfaces?

Answer (score 1):

When you are inheriting generic base class, you should specify base class constraints for generic type parameter as well:

```
public class SomeClass<T> : TheBaseClass<T>
 where T : Interface1, Interface2
{}
```

Comment: Thanks for the amazingly quick and accurate response.  Cheers.